# Why don't my signals fire slots without Qt::DirectConnection?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have a main class that launches a thread that performs a single action. I am trying to catch when the thread operations finish.

The main class:

```
// .h
class MainClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QThread thread;
// ...
public slots:
    void onFinish();
}

// .cpp
void MainClass::startThread()
{
    thread = new QThread();
    worker = new Worker();
    worker->moveToThread(thread);

    connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), worker, SLOT(process()));
    connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
    connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onFinish()));
    // connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onFinish()), Qt::DirectConnection);
}

void MainClass::onFinish()
{
    std::cout << "Finished!" << std::endl << std::flush;
}
```

The `Worker` class for the thread:

```
// .h
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Worker(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Worker();
public slots:
    void process();
signals:
    void finished();
}

// .cpp
void Worker::process()
{
    // ...Do stuff...

    emit finished();
}
```

Executing `startThread` does not print "Finished!". Why?

I have noticed that if I add `Qt::DirectConnection` to the line that connects to `onFinish()` (like in the commented line), the message is printed. But what can I do if I want to execute the `onFinish()` actions in the thread of the main class?

### Edit 1

In addition, it seems that the `finished()` -> `quit()` connect is also not working, because if I call `thread->isFinished()` or `thread->isRunning()`, after sleeping in the main thread to be sure that the thread task is completed, I obtain `false` and `true`, respectively.

### Edit 2

Since it may also be relevant, here is the main.cpp:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    std::unique_ptr <MainClass> mc = std::make_unique <MainClass>();

    mc->startThread();
    mc->thread->wait();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried without connecting to the `deleteLater()` slots? If it fires your `onFinish()` slot, you can call `deleteLater()` of both objects from there.

Comment: You may consider to put the `connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onFinish()));` before the connect to the `deleteLater()` slots.

Comment: Does the thread on which the `MainClass` instance is created have an active event loop? If not then queued signals will not be received.

Comment: @LoPiTaL, @mfreiholz: I have tried your suggestions. The message is still not printed. Also see my edit about ``isFinished()`` and ``isRunning()``. It looks like the problem is not related to ``deleteLater()``.

Comment: @G.M. I create an instance of ``MainClass`` in my "main.cpp", after starting a ``QCoreApplication``. Does that mean I have an event loop that prevents the signals from being received?

Comment: No, I mean that you need to have something like `qApp.exec()` or similar -- but I suspect that's what you're doing anyway.

Comment: Looks like you have no main event loop or at least it is never reached, because of your `wait()` call.

Comment: What does `mc->wait()` do?

Comment: Note that `a.quit()` prior to `a.exec()` is a no-op!

Answer (score 1):

On a first look I would say that the order of connections is important. The `deleteLater()` slots should always be the last methods.

```
connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), worker, SLOT(process()));
connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onFinish()));
connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
```

**Sitenode - QRunnable**
You might consider to use [QRunnable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrunnable.html) instead, which is designed for short running tasks/jobs. You can combine them with QObject or QFuture/QFutureWatcher to get notified as soon as they a finished.

## Update 1

Your main-event loop never starts and it looks like you want to exit the application when the task finishes. I don't think this is a nice implementation but these modifcations should work for you:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    std::unique_ptr<MainClass> mc = std::make_unique<MainClass>();
    mc->startThread();

    // do not wait!
    // let the main-event-loop handle events -> a.exec()
    // and quit() application by signal/slot

    return a.exec();
}

void MainClass::startThread()
{
    thread = new QThread();
    worker = new Worker();
    worker->moveToThread(thread);

    connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), worker, SLOT(process()));
    connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onFinish()));
    connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
    connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I solved my problem, although I am still not 100% sure what the problem was... I think G.M. was right about an active event loop preventing the slots from being executed, so the issue was not the order of "connect"s. I looked into your idea of using ``QRunnable`` and had a similar issue. Finally, I found a solution with ``QFuture`` and ``QtConcurrent::run``. But I cannot figure out why the last solution can work if the others didn't...